# Need to copy text file from one folder to another in windows using jmeter

Tags: shell, scripting, jmeter

My requirement is to copy text file from one folder to another in  windows OS using jmeter. So how can we achieve this using jmeter?

Please help!

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in at least 2 ways:

1. Using [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) configured like:

   [image: JMeter OS Process Sampler Copy File]
2. The faster (and cross-platform) way would be using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the code like:

   ```
   def sourceFile = new File('c:/somefolder/source_file.txt')
   def destinationFile = new File('c:/someotherfolder/destination_file.txt')
   destinationFile << sourceFile.text
   ```

   See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on using Groovy scripting in Jmeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

Use OS Process Sampler and write your command in Command field

see [Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)